# Compiler issues getting Go struct to implement an interface

Tags: go

I'm writing a REST client in Go to talk to a 3rd party "Fizz Buzz" API (doesn't matter what it does).

Here is my code:

```
// interfaces
//
type HttpClient interface {
    Do(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

type FizzBuzzApi interface {
    GetOrderById(ctx context.Context, orderId uuid.UUID) (FizzBuzzOrder, error)
    PlaceOrder(ctx context.Context, FizzBuzzOrder FizzBuzzOrder) error
}

// main impls
//
type FizzBuzzClient struct {
    host   string
    client *client.Client
}

func (fizzBuzzClient *FizzBuzzClient) PlaceOrder(ctx context.Context, fizzBuzzOrder FizzBuzzOrder) error {
  return nil
}

func (fizzBuzzClient *FizzBuzzClient) GetOrderById(ctx context.Context, orderId uuid.UUID) (FizzBuzzOrder, error) {
  return FizzBuzzOrder{},nil
}

// constructor
//
func New(h HttpClient, host string) *FizzBuzzClient {
    fc := &FizzBuzzClient{
        client: client.New(h),
        host:   host,
    }

    (*fc).client.ErrorResponseFunc = func(res *http.Response) (bool, error) {
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        return false, fmt.Errorf(string(b))
    }

    return fc
}

// test impls
//
type testFizzBuzzClient struct {}

func (c *testFizzBuzzClient) PlaceOrder(ctx context.Context, order fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzOrder) error {
    return nil
}

func (c *testFizzBuzzClient) GetOrderById(ctx context.Context, orderId uuid.UUID) (fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzOrder, error) {
  return fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzOrder{},nil
}
```

Then from inside `main.go` I have:

```
fc = fizzBuzz.New(&http.Client{}, "http://fizzbuzz.example.com")
orderId := orders.GetOrderHistory(*fc)
```

Where that `GetOrderHistory` function is:

```
func GetOrderHistory(fc fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzApi) FizzBuzzOrder {
  fbo,err := fc.GetOrderById(ctx, order.OrderId)
  return fbo
}
```

When the app starts up I get:

```
cannot use *fc (type fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzClient) as type fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzApi in argument to "github.com/myorg/myapp/server/accounts".GetOrderHistory:
    fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzClient does not implement fizzBuzz.FizzBuzzApi (GetOrderById method has pointer receiver)
```

Can anyone spot *why* my `FizzBuzzClient` is not implementing the `FizzBuzzApi`?

Comment: Yes, the compiler, and the error message details exactly why it does not implement the interface. The implementing method takes a pointer receiver, so you must cast a pointer to the struct in order for the value to implement the interface. You're using a value, not a pointer. In fact, you're doing so explicitly - `*fc` indicates you *have* a pointer, and you're explicitly dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetOrderHistory` gets a `FizzBuzzApi` interface, to which you send a struct that implements the `GetOrderById` method using a pointer receiver. That means, that method call may change the state of the receiver. However, you send a `FizzBuzzApi` implementation struct by value, instead of a pointer to that struct.

In short, instead of `*fc`, use `fc`.

Comment: Thanks @Burak (+1) please see my edits, I had a typo (it should _not_ have been `s.fc`). Does your answer still apply?

Comment: Use `fc` instead of `s.fc`